# jQuery/css not working with BigCommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bigcommerce

So I've got this nice little div button navigation menu setup here [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sketchs/vAx84/5/) and when I try to implement it on BigCommerce it doesn't work.  I am running into a problem when I try to add a snippet "%%Panel.ProductDescription%%" into the text.

So this is the code that I amended with the snippet

```
$("#description").on("click", function() {
    $("#content").text( % % Panel.ProductDescription % % );
});
```

I've tried .text, I've tried using .html, I've tried making it a variable and calling it. I'm out of ideas. Anyone come across this before? Before adding the snippet the code works beautifully. After adding it the code stops working.

Comment: what is `%%Panel.ProductDescription%%`? You might have to assign it to a `var` first n then use it

Comment: What contains the template variable %%Panel.ProductDescription%% ?

Comment: check console before posting something like that

Comment: I tried making it a var and it still didn't work. The panel contains product description information. The console said Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier . Probably due to the % maybe? I'm not sure how to debug it to be honest.

Comment: Are your % % spaced or like %% ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you are trying to insert the text `%%Panel.ProductDescription%%` you are targeting a Bigcommerce template shortcode. Once the template is rendered that shortcode is no longer accessible by any means - including jQuery.
When rendered that panel has the div id "ProductDescription". So your code should look more like this.

```
$("#description").on("click", function() {
    $("#content").text("#ProductDescription");
});
```

Note, however, that this div has other html in it. Either your jQuery should use `.html` instead of `.text` or you should think about targeting a div inside of the description panel.

`.ProductDescriptionContainer` is what actually holds the description content.